# Powershell equivalent of log4perl

Tags: powershell, logging

Coming from perl, I am looking for some 'standard' way to organize logging in powershell. Googling shows a lot of modules created by users but I am struggling to grasp if there is something like log4perl  or log4j.
I would like to  have one module/solution I can use across all ps scripts and avoid any changes in the future.

Answer (score 3):

There's [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) which is a port of log4j to the .NET Framework. Since Powershell is built on top of .NET, it may work for you. See also https://www.google.com/search?q=log4net+powershell